# Global maximum and minimum on closed ball

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, optimization

I want to find the global maximum and minimum of the function $f(x,y,z)=xy(1-x^2-y^2-z^2)$ on the closed unit ball? I guess they are (Maxima:$(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0), (-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2},0)$) and (Minima:$(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2},0), (-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0)$) but I need to prove this.

Comment: Remember that you use derivatives to find the interior extrema. Then you have to check on the boundary, which in this case is easy (hint: what is the value of $f$ on the sphere?)

Comment: $f(x,y,z) = 0$, when $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1$ i.e. unit ball. I think you mean in the closed unit ball...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that maximum and minimum values only differ in sign because you can change the sign of $xy$ without violating the constraint. So it suffices to find global maxima over part of the unit ball that is in the positive orthant. Using AM-GM inequality we have $$4f(x,y,z)\leq \left(\frac{1-x^2+2xy-y^2-z^2}{2}\right)^2\\ =\left(\frac{1-(x-y)^2-z^2}{2}\right)^2\\ \leq\frac{1}{4}.$$ The first inequality becomes equations only when $2xy=1-x^2-y^2-z^2$ and the second inequality when $x=y$ and $z=0$. Thus maximum of $f$ is attained at $x=y=\frac{1}{2}$ and $z=0$. The other maxima is in the negative orthant that we excluded. Using the sign argument above minima are also at the points you mentioned.